# dataframe.py", in __getattr__ AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage
from pandas import DataFrame



from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
  
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName('Optimize BigQuery Storage') \
  .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.24.2') \
  .getOrCreate()
  
df = spark.read.text('gs://test111/test/test.txt', lineSep=",")
  
#df.selectExpr("split(value, ',') as\
#Text_Data_In_Rows_Using_Text").show(4,False)

df.show()

sProjectID = 'prj-d-xxxx-ingest'
sTargetDataset = 'data'
sTargetTable = 'xxx'

client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = 'data.xxx'

# Since string columns use the "object" dtype, pass in a (partial) schema
# to ensure the correct BigQuery data type.
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=[
    bigquery.SchemaField("Source_Code", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("FLAG", "STRING")
])

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, table_id, job_config=job_config
)
```

**ERROR as below**
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1643, in **getattr**
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: I am trying to read txt file from GCS and write it to Bigquery. google Cloud

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `google.cloud.bigquery`, you can use BigQuery connector with spark to write data to BQ. See [BQ connector with spark document](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example).

Assuming that your data is already correct on your `df` variable. You can apply this code to write the data to BQ:

```
gcs_bucket="your-gcs-bucket" #If not provided, it will create a temporary bucket for this

df.write.format("bigquery").option("table","dataset.your_table_here").option("temporaryGcsBucket", gcs_bucket).mode("append").save()
#.mode() can be either 'append' or 'overwrite'
```

I executed the code using `spark-submit` with Spark BigQuery jar:

```
spark-submit --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar my_script.py
```

See logs after running the script:

[image]